# What indexes should be used while doing an inner join in foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, indexing, inner-join

Database : MySql

I have two tables Student, class linked by foreign key relationship as below :

```
create table class
(
id int(10) not null,
primary key(id)
);

create table Student(
id int(10) not null,
cid int(10) not null,
constraint foreign key(cid) references class(id)
);
```

Both of these tables have 6000+ rows.

Now when i do an inner join as below :

```
select * from Student inner join class on Student.ci = class.id
```

Explain plan seems to use index only on table & it uses full table scan on other. I think it should use indexes on both the tables.

The index is shown in possible keys in EXPLAIN PLAN but not used...

Comment: Index isn't used with small amount of rows because it's pointless to use it. With larger amount of rows, where index actually does help to inspect less rows, it will be used. Try to fill your database with a few hundred thousand records and test again.

Comment: SQL server uses "statistics" to determine the best way a query should run.  The query optimiser is actually pretty clever, and if it decides the cost to use an index is higher than accessing the table, it'll access the table.

Comment: any hints which say that index is not being used specifically due to low number of rows?

Comment: I tried with 6000+ rows, still only one index being used...

Comment: Are there any indexes on the student table?

Comment: Yes, The one mysql creates automatically for a foreign key constraint...

Comment: Job of the index is to reduce traversing across the data-set (table with data). If the index won't help this traversal, MySQL ignores it. Ignore occurs when: index cardinality is low (number of unique index values across the data set) or when MySQL calculates through its statistics that it doesn't pay off to use the index (I wont throw numbers around here because I forgot them). You can always force the index using `FORCE INDEX` and you'll probably notice that performance of your query is a bit slower. If you have 2 indexes and MySQL won't use it - it's always for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what indexes were built for you.

For this one query (`select * from Student inner join class on Student.ci = class.id`), you need either

```
Student:  INDEX(ci)  and/or
class:    INDEX(id)
```

Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is an index, so you already have what is needed on `class`.

Why a "full scan"?  Because you did not give a `WHERE` clause to say that you wanted anything less than a full scan.

For a query like that, the Optimizer will

- Do a table scan on one of the tables, and
- For each row in that table, reach over to the other table, preferably using an index.  ("Nested Loop Join").

That's the best way to execute that query.

When the `EXPLAIN` says "Using index" it means that it is using a "covering index".  That is all the work can be done in the index, without looking into the data.

(If you showed us the `EXPLAIN`, I could be more explicit.`